# How to use python to design a graphical user interface on raspberry pi?

Tags: python, gui

How to use python to program a graphical interface on raspberry pi? It supposes to be like a small software which has simple or just some function of audacity, displaying spectrum of the sound signals and the volume should be able to be controlled by users. Something like oscilloscope.
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: This question has been closed once as too broad.  You seem to have done no research since the last question was closed.

Answer (score 1):

There're quite a few tool kits available for GUI designing. Such as `PyGTK`,`PyQt`, `Tkinter`,`PySide`,`PyGame` to name a few.

`Tkinter` is python wrapper around Tcl GUI tool kit which is installed on Rpi by default. It's quite simple yet powerful library.

Hope it helps.